# Error "No Method" when using delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-parsing, delayed-job

I'm trying to import 90k lines of xml into my ruby app.  herokus timeout limit is 30s so i'm trying to use delayed job.

The import class works wonderfully in around 48-hippopotomuses locally.  When i add the line

```
  handle_asynchronously :save_races
```

I get the error "undefined method `save_races' for class`Xmltube'"

What am i doing wrong with DJ and how can i get this to work?

Full class code below

```
require "rexml/document"
class Xmltube  
  def self.convert_save(xml_data)
    doc = REXML::Document.new xml_data.read                        
    doc.elements.each("Meeting") do |meeting_element| 
      meeting = save_meeting(meeting_element)
      save_races(meeting_element, meeting)
      Rails.logger.info "all done"      
    end
  end

  def self.save_races(meeting_element,  meeting)

    meeting_element.elements.each("Races/Race") do |race_element|      
      race = save_race(race_element, meeting) 
      save_race_entrants(race_element, race)                        
    end
  end

  def self.save_race_entrants(race_element, race)
    race_element.elements.each("RaceEntries/RaceEntry") do |entry_element|
      horse = save_horse(entry_element)
      jockey = save_jockey(entry_element)
      start = save_start(entry_element, horse, jockey, race) 
      save_sumaries(entry_element, start)
    end   
  end 

  def self.save_track(meeting_element)
    # there is only one track, but still, each? wtf.
    t = {}
    meeting_element.elements.each("Track") do |track|        
      t = {
        :name       =>  track.attributes["VenueName"],
        :track_code =>  track.attributes["VenueCode"],          
        :condition  =>  track.elements['TrackRating'].text,
        :club_id    =>  save_club(meeting_element.elements["Club"]).id
      }         
    end    

    track = Track.where(:track_code =>  t[:track_code]  ).first  
    if track
      Track.update(track.id, t)    
    else      
      Track.create(t)        
    end    
  end

  def self.save_meeting meeting_element
    t = {
      :meet_code  =>  meeting_element.attributes['MeetCode'],          
      :stage      =>  meeting_element.elements["MeetingStage"].text,          
      :phase      =>  meeting_element.elements["MeetingPhase"].text,          
      :nominations_close_at =>  meeting_element.elements["NominationsClose"].text, 
      :acceptance_close_at =>   meeting_element.elements["AcceptanceClose"].text,           
      :riders_close_at      =>  meeting_element.elements["RidersClose"].text,           
      :weights_published_at =>  meeting_element.elements["WeightsPublishing"].text,          
      :club_id =>  save_club(meeting_element.elements["Club"]).id ,
      :track_id => save_track(meeting_element).id,
      :tab_status =>  meeting_element.elements["TabStatus"].text, 
      :state =>  meeting_element.elements["StateDesc"].text, 
      :day_night =>  meeting_element.elements["DayNight"].text, 
      :number_of_races =>  meeting_element.elements["NumOfRaces"].text, 
      :meet_date =>  meeting_element.elements["MeetDate"].text, 
    }         


    meeting = Meeting.where(:meet_code =>  t[:meet_code]  ).first  
    if meeting
      Meeting.update(meeting.id, t)    
    else      
      Meeting.create(t)        
    end    
  end

  ############################################################

  def self.save_sumaries entry_element, start  
    entry_element.elements.each('Form/ResultsSummaries/ResultsSummary') do | element |
      s = {
        :name             =>  element.attributes['Name'],
        :start_id         =>  start.id,
        :starts           =>  element.attributes['Starts'],
        :wins             =>  element.attributes['Wins'],
        :seconds          =>  element.attributes['Seconds'],
        :thirds           =>  element.attributes['Thirds'],
        :prize_money      =>  element.attributes['PrizeMoney'],        
      }

      sum = Summary.where(:name =>  s[:name] ).where(:start_id => s[:start_id]).first  
      if sum
        Summary.update(sum.id, s)    
      else      
        Summary.create(s)        
      end 
    end     
  end

  def self.save_start entry_element, horse, jockey, race
    s = {
      :horse_id    =>  horse.id,
      :jockey_id   =>  jockey.id,
      :race_id     =>  race.id,
      :silk        =>  entry_element.elements["JockeySilksImage"].attributes["FileName_NoExt"], 
      :start_code  =>  entry_element.attributes['RaceEntryCode'],
      :handicap_weight =>  entry_element.elements['HandicapWeight'].text, 
    }
   # Rails.logger.info entry_element['HandicapWeight'].text
    start = Start.where(:start_code =>  s[:start_code]  ).first  
    if start
      Start.update(start.id, s)    
    else      
      Start.create(s)        
    end  
  end

  def self.save_jockey entry_element
    j={
      :name         =>  entry_element.elements['JockeyRaceEntry/Name'].text,
      :jockey_code  =>  entry_element.elements['JockeyRaceEntry'].attributes["JockeyCode"],
    }
    jockey = Jockey.where(:jockey_code =>  j[:jockey_code]  ).first  
    if jockey
      Jockey.update(jockey.id, j)    
    else      
      Jockey.create(j)        
    end      
  end

  def self.save_horse entry_element
    trainer = save_trainer entry_element
    h= {
      :name       =>  entry_element.elements['Horse'].attributes["HorseName"],          
      :color      =>  entry_element.elements['Horse'].attributes["Colour"],          
      :dob        =>  entry_element.elements['Horse'].attributes["FoalDate"],           
      :sex        =>  entry_element.elements['Horse'].attributes["Sex"],           
      :trainer_id =>  trainer.id,
      :horse_code =>  entry_element.elements['Horse'].attributes["HorseCode"],                 
    }
    horse = Horse.where(:horse_code =>  h[:horse_code]  ).first  
    if horse
      Horse.update(horse.id, h)    
    else      
      Horse.create(h)        
    end        
  end

  def self.save_trainer entry_element
    t= {
        :name         =>  entry_element.elements['Trainer/Name'].text,
        :trainer_code =>  entry_element.elements['Trainer'].attributes["TrainerCode"]  
      }
    trainer = Trainer.where(:trainer_code =>  t[:trainer_code]  ).first  
    if trainer
      Trainer.update(trainer.id, t)    
    else      
      Trainer.create(t)        
    end    
  end  

  def self.save_club element
    t = {}      
      t = {
        :club_code  =>  element.attributes['ClubCode'],          
        :title      =>  element.attributes["Title"],          
      }             
    club = Club.where(:club_code =>  t[:club_code]  ).first  
    if club
      Club.update(club.id, t)    
    else      
      Club.create(t)        
    end    
  end

  def self.save_race element, meeting
    r = {
        :name       =>  element.elements['NameRaceFull'].text,
        :occur      =>  element.elements['RaceStartTime'].attributes["TimeAtVenue"],          
        :distance   =>  element.elements['RaceDistance'].text,
        :race_type  =>  element.elements['RaceType'].text,
        :track_id   =>  meeting.track_id,
        :race_code  =>  element.attributes["RaceCode"],
        :meeting_id => meeting.id       
      }        
    race = Race.where(:race_code =>  r[:race_code]  ).first  
    if race
      Race.update(race.id, r)    
    else      
      Race.create(r)        
    end  
  end

  handle_asynchronously :save_races
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `save_races` is a class method, you should call `handle_asynchronously` on `Xmltube`'s singleton class:

```
class << self
  handle_asynchronously :save_races
end
```

Comment: Thanks. whilst that avoids the error, it isn't returning the request any faster when running locally, even though the delayed job service in terminal shows "Job Delayed::PerformableMethod (id=19) RUNNING"

Comment: I think you should move all `convert_save` method to DJ if you want request to be handled faster.

Comment: ok, but calling that like this:  Xmltube.delay.convert_save(params[:dump][:file])  gives the undefined method "name" on nil class and the same error if use      handle_asynchronously :convert_save  -

Comment: that last - even if its in the class << self block

Answer (score 0):

This just worked as I would expect

```
class Foo
  def self.bar(s)
    Rails.logger.info "From Foo.bar('#{s}')"
  end
end

# then ...
Foo.delay.bar('hello')
```

I was running 4.0.4 of DJ with ruby 2.1